# What is the correct pronunciation of "pizza"?

Tags: pronunciation

I have a friend who is constantly suggesting we eat "Pixa" for dinner. It grinds me every time she says "Pixa", so I am trying to make sure it is truly incorrect to pronounce the 'x' sound in this situation before I try to correct her.

Comment: Is it really so hard to find a video of someone using the word 'pizza'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it wrong to pronounce "pizza" as "peedtza"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6809/is-it-wrong-to-pronounce-pizza-as-peedtza)

Answer (score 5):

The correct pronunciation is /ˈpiːtsə/